# Choosing the better half in several permutations simultaneously

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Given a permutation $a_1,\ldots,a_{2 n}$ of integers $\{1,\ldots,2n\}$, a choice of $n$ integers is called *good* if:

- At least one of the first two numbers $\{a_1,a_2\}$ is chosen;
- At least two of the first four numbers $\{a_1,\ldots,a_4\}$ are chosen; ...
- For every $\ell\leq n$, at least $\ell$ of the first $2 \ell$ numbers $\{a_1,\ldots,a_{2\ell}\}$ are chosen.

For example, when $n=2$ there are $5$ good choices: $\{a_1,a_2\}$, $\{a_1,a_3\}$, $\{a_1,a_4\}$ $\{a_2,a_3\}$ $\{a_2,a_4\}$. <sub>(In general, the number of good choices is the $(n+1)$-th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), ${2n+2\choose n+1}/(n+2)$.)</sub>

Now, suppose there is another permutation $b_1,\ldots,b_{2n}$, and we want a choice that is good for *both* permutations simultaneously. Now the number of choices is much smaller, but there always exists at least one, and it can be found by the following algorithm:

- Choose either $a_1$ or $a_2$, whichever appears earlier in permutation $b$;
- Choose either $a_3$ or $a_4$, whichever appears earlier in permutation $b$;
  ...
- Choose either $a_{2n-1}$ or $a_{2n}$, whichever appears earlier in permutation $b$.

For example, if the permutations are $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ and $6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1$, then the choice $\{1, 3, 5\}$ is good simultaneously for both permutations, but the choice $\{1,2,3\}$ is not.

What if there are $k\geq 3$ permutations? What is the largest $k$ such that a simultanoues good choice exists for every $k$ permutations?